# Speed up computing the row-wise median of every 3-tuple of columns

Tags: r, performance, function, dataframe, median

If I have a data frame as such:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 5000, 100))
```

I can use the following function to get every combination of three-term medians row-wise:

```
median_df = t(apply(df, 1, combn, 3, median))
```

The problem is, this function will take several hours to run. The culprit is median(), which takes about ten times longer to run than max() or min().

How can I speed this function up, possibly by writing a faster version of median() or working with the original data differently?

**Update:**

If I run the above code but only for df[,1:10] as such:

```
median_df = t(apply(df[,1:10], 1, combn, 3, median))
```

takes 29 seconds

```
fastMedian_df = t(apply(df[,1:10], 1, combn, 3, fastMedian))
```

from the package ccaPP takes 6.5 seconds

```
max_df = t(apply(df[,1:10], 1, combn, 3, max))
```

takes 2.5 seconds

So we see a significant improvement with fastMedian(). Can we still do better?

Comment: While `median` may pose somewhat of problem in comparison to `max` and `min`, I think the real issue with `combn`. For example, a single row (`system.time(combn(df[1,], 3))`) takes ~ 10 seconds on my machine.

Comment: @nrussell while combnPrim is a much faster implementation of combn(), I cannot get combnPrim to work in this case, returning error: Error in if (simplify) { : argument is not interpretable as logical

Comment: In any case, combn() takes less than 10% of the time median() takes to run in this function

Comment: If anyone remembers the name of the user who wrote an answer using Rcpp, could you give me his username? He deleted his answer, however I wanted to keep it on because it is scalable to finding four-value, five-value, etc. medians.

Comment: His name started with "ed"

Comment: In case the answer isn't re-posted, I had their function in my IDE. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/e71dc3df3b93d62ad0aa).

Comment: @nrussell Awesome. Thanks. Could you elaborate on how I turn that code into an R function?

Comment: Just save the file as something, e.g. `median_rcpp.cpp`, and call `Rcpp::sourceCpp("median_rcpp.cpp")` (assuming your have `Rcpp installed).

Comment: @JamesH I've updated the Rcpp example in my answer to handle the median of any number of columns in a vectorized way.

Comment: @JamesH It was user [ekstroem](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4288660/ekstroem).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One approach to speed things up would be to note that the median of three numbers is their sum minus their max minus their min. This means we can vectorize our median calculations by handling each triple of columns once (performing the median for all rows in the same calculation) instead of handling it once for each row.

```
set.seed(144)
# Fully random matrix
df = matrix(rnorm(50000), 5000, 10)
original <- function(df) t(apply(df, 1, combn, 3, median))
josilber <- function(df) {
  combos <- combn(seq_len(ncol(df)), 3)
  apply(combos, 2, function(x) rowSums(df[,x]) - pmin(df[,x[1]], df[,x[2]], df[,x[3]]) - pmax(df[,x[1]], df[,x[2]], df[,x[3]]))
}
system.time(res.josilber <- josilber(df))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.117   0.009   0.149 
system.time(res.original <- original(df))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  15.107   1.864  16.960 
all.equal(res.josilber, res.original)
# [1] TRUE
```

The vectorization yields a 110x speedup when there are 10 columns and 5000 rows. Unfortunately I do not have a machine with enough memory to store the 808.5 million numbers in the output for your full example.

You could speed this up further by implementing a Rcpp function that takes as input the vector representation of a matrix (aka the vector obtained by reading the matrix down the columns) along with the number of rows and returns the median of each column. The function relies heavily on the `std::nth_element` function, which is asymptotically linear in the number of elements you're taking a median of. (Note that I don't average the middle two values when I take the median of an even-length vector; I instead take the lower of the two).

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
"NumericVector vectorizedMedian(NumericVector x, int chunkSize) {
 const int n = x.size() / chunkSize;
 std::vector<double> input = Rcpp::as<std::vector<double> >(x);
  NumericVector res(n);
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::nth_element(input.begin()+i*chunkSize, input.begin()+i*chunkSize+chunkSize/2,
                     input.begin()+(i+1)*chunkSize);
    res[i] = input[i*chunkSize+chunkSize/2];
  }
  return res;
}")
```

Now we just invoke this function instead of using `rowSums`, `pmin` and `pmax`:

```
josilber.rcpp <- function(df) {
  combos <- combn(seq_len(ncol(df)), 3)
  apply(combos, 2, function(x) vectorizedMedian(as.vector(t(df[,x])), 3))
}
system.time(josilber.rcpp(df))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.049   0.008   0.081 
all.equal(josilber(df), josilber.rcpp(df))
# [1] TRUE
```

In total we therefore get a 210x speedup; 110x of the speedup is from switching from a non-vectorized application of `median` to a vectorized application and the remaining 2x speedup is from switching from a combination of `rowSums`, `pmin`, and `pmax` for computing the median in a vectorized way to a Rcpp-based approach.

Comment: Does it make sense to vectorize in the other dimension? There will be 161700 combinations of 3 for 100 columns, but only 5000 rows of data.

Comment: @MartinMorgan I don't immediately see how you would do it, but you are certainly right that the output is wider than it is long.

Comment: `t(apply(df, 1, function(y) vectorizedMedian(y[combos], 3)))` but in the end it doesn't seem to make much difference.

Comment: @josilber After I am finished running this function, the memory used by the R session doesn't return to its pre-run value. For example, if I run it for the above matrix, but with 40 columns, it will reach a value of 1.6 gb memory used. The function will finish running, but the memory will stay at the max value, and will only balloon if I run the function more times, forcing me to restart the R session.

Comment: @JamesH yes, the function returns an enormous matrix, so as long as you have that matrix stored as a variable it will take up memory in your R session. You can remove a variable `var` with `rm(var)` and run garbage collection with `gc()` to free up memory.

Comment: @josilber It appears that even when I store the function output as a variable and then `rm()` that variable, the memory is still used

Comment: @JamesH did you run `gc()` afterwards?

Comment: @josilber that took care of it.